# Message format issue for RabbitMQ shoveled payload to ActiveMQ Classic

Tags: rabbitmq, activemq-classic, rabbitmq-shovel

I have a setup where a queue in RabbitMQ shovels the data to a queue in ActiveMQ Clasic 6.0.1 over AMQP (1.0).

When posting the following data (JSON) from RabbitMQ

```
{"hello": "world"}
```

I am receiving the below on ActiveMQ Classic web console. I go to the queue, and see list of message, and view the message. The details appear in the message details area:

```
Sr�Ss�
@@@@@@@@@@@@@St�/�exchange��routing_key�RMQ�    src-queue�RMQSu�{"hello": "world"}
```

Is there a way I can only have the JSON only? Is there a particular setting, or is this something pretty standard for payload over AMQP?

Comment: v6.0.1 - classic

Comment: I am posting it over from the RabbitMQ web console (for the testing purpose)

Comment: I am receiving the message using the ActiveMQ web console, I don't have any consumer attached yet.

Comment: I go to the queue, and see list of message, and view the message. The details appear in the message details area.

Comment: Actually it's just JSON, so when I post a message using to a queue on RabbitMQ, and peak the message, I get JSON back. When it shovels to ActiveMQ (over AMQP) that's when the JSON contains some extra characters and properties as stated above. The shovel settings itself does not specify any message format / translation scheme as such.

Comment: I am not explicitly specifying any translation from AMQP 0.9.1 to 1.0. The only thing which I am configuring is the Source (AMQP 0.9.1) and the Destination (AMQP 1.0) queues and uri. Not doing any header forwarding.

Comment: For the encoding, I am using String which is the Default payload encoding in RabbitMQ web console.

Comment: I even tried sending the message as Base64 encoded, but still I see the special characters prepended with properties included

Comment: Introducing actual consumer and producer made no difference as such in the behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ActiveMQ web console is showing the AMQP message contained within the native ActiveMQ Openwire message instance. This occurs usually because the broker [AMQP transformer](https://activemq.apache.org/components/classic/documentation/amqp) is set to Native or Raw as opposed the JMS which would fully convert the AMQP message into an ActiveMQ native Message (this can cause unexpected alterations in the message though).

The web console is giving you the full truth of what the Message contents are and can't be altered to somehow know what an AMQP message body looks like vs any other message body so this is what you should expect to see.

Comment: Thanks, setting the AMQP transformer to JMS resolved the issue.